# i have made an module to add two integer, but calling it gives me "none" answer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm beginner and learning to code,

Here is Module:

```
class extfile:
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y
```

Here is the Program:

```
class A:
    def a(x, y):
        extfile.add(x,y)    
print(A.a(4,5))
```

Here is the Output:

> None

Comment: add a `return` in `A.a` before your call to `extfile.add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class A's method a is not returning anything:

```
class extfile:
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y

class A:
    def a(x, y):
        return extfile.add(x,y)

print(A.a(4,5))
#output: 9
```